# Symfony EasyAdmin Bundle how to filter select options

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I'm using symfony 3 + EasyAdmin bundle, in some entities I have a field "Sectors" that create a relation to another entity "Sector".

Automatically EasyAdmin give me a select with all the sectors where the user can choose from.

I need that the user (that is associated to one or more sectors), can modify (add or remove relations) only if that relations are in its sectors (in other words, if I'm the user and I'm associated to sectors A and B, if I publish (or edit) a news I can set(add/remove) the news sectors only to A and/or B)...

How can I achieve that?

As I can see the form are handled by the symfony standard form component.

Comment: https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/issues/1145